# TruTrak Vision PMA Autopilot Limitations for coupled instrument procedures- C172M - STC SA04231CH

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, instrument-procedures, autopilot, checkride

I am currently flying a Cessna 172M with a TruTrak Vision Autopilot installed under STC SA04231CH.  Section 2.4 of the approved AFMS states:

> This autopilot has not been evaluated by the FAA to meet the
> certification requirements for coupled instrument procedures,
> including coupled approaches. Therefore, these types of procedures are
> not authorized without further evaluation and approval.

The remark concerning "coupled approaches" is clear.  However, does "coupled instrument procedures" remark mean that the autopilot is essentially a 'VFR operations only" system?  My IRA check ride is coming up soon and I'm trying to understand what I can and cannot use the autopilot for, and therefore what I can be tested on.

Thank you for any comments.

Comment: I don’t have an answer for you.  But I would definitely reach out to Honeywell/Bendix-King, as they acquired TruTrak a few years ago.  Or your avionics shop.  You *really* need to know the answer prior to your check ride.  You need to fully understand the IFR applicability of every system in the panel and be prepared to discuss with the DPE.  He or she will *not* be OK with “I’m not sure so I’m just not going to use it for approaches.”

Comment: (Continued) Remember too that a flight control system is really the combination of the GPS navigator, Attitude Indicator, HSI/DG, and autopilot.  It is an approach capable autopilot so my assumption is that your plane has a GPS, or AI/HSI that are unable to support vertical nav modes.  You *may* still be able to use it in HDG mode to fly holds, and in NAV mode to track a radial with altitude hold.

Comment: Thank you, Max. This is helpful. The aircraft does have a GNS 430W and is capable of LPV approaches. I’ll reach out direct to Bendix-King tomorrow.  Much appreciated.